# Magento CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file

Tags: php, magento

I'm having some troubles with installing extensions with magento connect. When I start installing the extension the outline terminal writes something like this:

> Checking dependencies of packages Installing package community/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts 0.7.4
>
> CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file
>   /var/www/magento/downloader/.cache/community/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts-0.7.4/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurabl

I checked the path and I found the requested file. As you can see the permissions should be fine ;-)

> drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Nov  3 11:10 Configurabl

I have no idea what to do. I'm using PHP 5.5.4-1 - so that should be fine.

Do you have any idea what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error, in this case, comes from a php security mod that checks files on upload. There seems to be some non-ascii characters in one of the extracted files from the package and as soon as it encounters them it halts processing the file, hence the "Configurabl" is cut short.

What you need to do to get past this error is either adjust the settings of your uploader security mod, but most likely you don't have access to that.  The other option is to download the package some other way (in this case it is available on Github at https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple), extract it and upload the files via FTP.

Comment: how to fix this. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40125/connect-error-failed-to-open-file-on-extension-package-testing

Answer (score 10):

Go

> downloader\lib\Mage\Archive\Tar.php

find method

```
_extractFileHeader().
```

Then find the near code line no 563:

```
if (!($header['name'] == '././@LongLink' && $header['type'] == 'L')) {
  $header['name'] = trim($header['name']);
  return $header;
}
```

And replace it with:

```
if (!(trim($header['name']) == '././@LongLink' && $header['type'] == 'L')) {
 $header['name'] = trim($header['name']);
 return $header;
}
```

[image]

See on dev. comment: [enter link description here](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Extension-Package-installation-error-2083430.S.5929167301688442883?trk=groups_items_see_more-0-b-ttl)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the tyranny of the [PHP's error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).  Where by tyranny I mean minor annoyance in the grand scheme of things.

All those console errors are driven by exceptions.  If you search the Magento Connect source in `downloader`, you'll find the exception text

> Failed to open file

is only used in three places

```
$ ack 'Failed to open file'
lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File/Bz.php
47:            throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to open file ' . $this->_filePath);

lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File/Gz.php
44:            throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to open file ' . $this->_filePath);

lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File.php
190:            throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to open file ' . $this->_filePath);
```

If you look at each of those places, you'll see a similar pattern

```
protected function _open($mode)
{
    $this->_fileHandler = @bzopen($this->_filePath, $mode);

    if (false === $this->_fileHandler) {
        throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to open file ' . $this->_filePath);
    }
}

protected function _open($mode)
{
    $this->_fileHandler = @fopen($this->_filePath, $mode);

    if (false === $this->_fileHandler) {
        throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to open file ' . $this->_filePath);
    }
}

protected function _open($mode)
{
    $this->_fileHandler = @gzopen($this->_filePath, $mode);

    if (false === $this->_fileHandler) {
        throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to open file ' . $this->_filePath);
    }
}
```

The developers who built Magento Connect used the `@` operator to suppress the real PHP errors that emit from `gzopen`, `fopen`, and `bzopen`.

If I was in your situation, I'd temporarily edit these files to remove the `@` operator from these function calls, and then check my error logs/browser output to see why PHP didn't want to open these files.

Comment: Very good idea! I tried it but the output is exactly the same and there is nothing (new) in my error log :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner and permissions of `/var/www/magento/downloader/`.  If you have SSH/command line access then you can install your extension like from the root of your Magento installation like this:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts
```

If you get any permission errors running `mage` then change permissions to 755 with `chmod 755 mage` (or `sudo chmod 755 mage`).

Comment: I tried the mage install with two different extension. And I got exactly the same issue „install: Failed to open file“ - I set all the permissions to 777 for testing but that doesn't change anything :(

Comment: I just noticed something about your install.  It looks like your filename is getting cut off -- `Configurabl`.  Do you have some kind of limit for the length of your file path in your config?

Comment: I don't now about any limits. Basically the folder „Cofigurabl“ really  exists.

When I try to install another app the „missing“ file is the following: /downloader/.cache/community/m2epro_ebay_magento-6.0.7/app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Block/Adminhtml/Wizard/InstallationEbay/Installation/ModeConfirmation/ - Basically this one also exists.

Comment: Try turning on `open_basedir`.  Maybe that is stopping the system from seeing the file.

Comment: open_basedir was disabled. I set it to /var/www/ but the error still appears

Comment: Have you tried it outside of Magento's downloader?  Give the `./mage` command I mentioned from the command line a try.

Comment: Make sure that `phpinfo()` shows open_basedir as being set correctly.

Comment: I tried the mage command in my terminal and exactly the same issue occured. phpinfo() shows hat the open_basedir was set to /var/www/ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue here is that Magento Connect has an issue when using php 5.5 - its to do with path length, Only started once I updated to 5.5 this week. - if this is your issue (check your php version) you have 2 options : You can install the extension manually or downgrade your php version.

I don't have enough cred points to vote up an answer but I thought it best let people know that ravi patel's TRIM solution fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

simply change the file permissions. index.php file to give 644